# Search wont show on same page

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have three files; index.php, searchbar.php and search.php

now when i have search.php show its results on its own page its fine but when i try to include the search page in index.php i get nothing.

so i include the searchbox.php in index.php so i have a search bar, i then search for something and include the search.php page by using the $_GET['p'] on the index.php but the search always come up blank, if i just leave search.php as its own page and dont try to include it then i get my results but id like for them to be included on the page they were searched from.

index.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] != "") {

$p = $_GET['p'];

if (file_exists('include/'.$p.'.php')) {

@include ('include/'.$p.'.php');

} elseif (!file_exists('include/'.$p.'.php')) {

echo 'Page you are requesting doesn´t exist<br><br>';

}

} else {

@include ('news.php');

}

?>
```

searchbox.php

```
<div id="searchwrapper"><form action="?p=search" method="get">
<input type="text" class="searchbox" name="query" value=""  id="query"/>
<input type="image" src="search.png" class="searchbox_submit" value=""  ALT="Submit Form" id="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

search.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php'; 
$searchTerms = $_GET['query'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM misc WHERE itemname LIKE  '%$searchTerms%' ORDER BY itemname ");

{
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' width=608 id='misc' class='tablesorter'><thead>";
echo "<tr> <th> </th> <th>Item Name</th> <th>Desc.</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {

    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td width=50>";
    echo $row['image'];
    echo "</td><td width=150>";
    echo $row['itemname'];
    echo "</td><td width=250>";
    echo $row['desc'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
}

echo "</tbody></table>";;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0)
{
  echo 'No Results';
}
?>
```

Comment: take out all the leading @'s and make sure error checking is on

Comment: white page usually means an error, with show errors being off,  sure errors are on and showing, or check error log

Comment: i think i explained the problem a little wrong, index.php loads fine even when the search.php is included after searchbox.php is used just no search results are shown, its like the page isnt actually included, normally when i include a page on link the adress gets ?p=pagename at the end but when i try to include search.php using searchbox.php i just get the ?query=searchsubject page where i would be expecting to see ?p=search?query=searchsubject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I reproduced your code, the "p=search" wasn't carrying over.  The better way to set it up is to have the action just go to your index.php file and have a hidden input with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="search" />
```

That will work properly for you!

Answer (score 0):

A blank page almost always means you have whitespace after your closing `?>`. Remove the closing `?>` in index.php and search.php - this will force the preprocessor to dynamically determine EOF, which is exactly what you want (and what nearly every PHP framework/company includes within their coding standards).