# search result not showing in the same window

Tags: javascript, php, html

my search result does not show on the same window, i would want the result to be displayed on the same window. i have found the same question but the code is different from what I'm using so i cant relate to it: [Search wont show on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213670/search-wont-show-on-same-page)

scenario 1:

if I put in the `action="search_result2.php"` - it will redirect the result on the other page

scenario 2:

if i used `action=""` in this code below, its not doing anything

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#results").show();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search").on('click',function() {
            var find = $('#find').val();
            var field = $('#field').val();
            $.post('search_result2.php',{find:find, field:field}, function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" style="width:auto">
<div id="mainContent">

 <h2>Search</h2> 
 <form name="search" method="post" action="">
 Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" id="find" /> in 
 <Select NAME="field" id="field">
 <Option VALUE="testA">A</option>
 <Option VALUE="testB">B</option>
 <Option VALUE="testC">C</option>
 <Option VALUE="testD">D</option>
 </Select>
 <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
 <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Search" />
 </form>

<div id="results">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my search_result2.php:

```
<?php

 //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
if (isset($_POST['searching']) && $_POST['searching'] == "yes") 
{ 
echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 

//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
if (empty($_POST['find'])) 
{ 
echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
exit; 
} 

 // Otherwise we connect to our Database 
 mysql_connect("host", "username", "passw") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error()); 

 // We preform a bit of filtering 
 $find = strtoupper($_POST['find']); 
 $find = strip_tags($_POST['find']); 
 $find = trim ($_POST['find']); 
 $field = trim ($_POST['field']);

 //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'"); 


 //And we display the results 
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 echo $result['testA']; 
 echo " "; 
 echo $result['testB']; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo $result['testC']; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo $result['testD']; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 } 

 //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
 } 

 //And we remind them what they searched for 
 echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: I'm not an expert for jQuery, but why you have two `$(document).ready(function(){}`?

Comment: first one is for the `div results`; second one is for the script to post the result on the same page

Comment: Can you check your console if there are any errors?

Comment: i dont know what u mean...but im not getting any error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load in the same page, without refreshing the page, you'll need to make an ajax request.

If you can reload the page, the php part must be in the same "location" as your original link.
For example if you put that code on the top of the same file with the form (and rename it with a .php extension), it should work (if the php can interpret in that folder).